# How to create key:value list from JSON? Key name should contain some values from object itself

Tags: json, bash, jq

I'm trying to parse JSON and store certain values as metrics in Graphite.
In order to make my Graphite more user-friendly I have to form a metric name, that contains some values from its object.
I got working solution on bash loops + jq, but it's really slow. So I'm asking for help :)

Here is my input:

```
{
...
  },
  "Johnny Cage": {
    "firstname": "Johnny",
    "lastname": "Cage",
    "height": 183,
    "weight": 82,
    "hands": 2,
    "legs": 2,
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

Desired output:

```
mk.fighter.Johnny.Cage.firstname Johnny
mk.fighter.Johnny.Cage.lastname Cage
mk.fighter.Johnny.Cage.height 183
mk.fighter.Johnny.Cage.weight 82
mk.fighter.Johnny.Cage.hands 2
mk.fighter.Johnny.Cage.legs 2
...
```

Comment: Show the code that you have

Comment: It's really ugly :) Let's assume I don't have it ? :) Otherwise I wouldn't ask for help. It's 'bash madness' with awk/grep/sed/jq/etc. Basically it getting keys, then loop thru them, parsing each object seperately, getting required values and forming prefix, then adding it to each line of pretty formatted JSON as text. The main problem is bash loop and amount of jq calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With single **`jq`** command:

Sample `input.json`:

```
{
  "Johnny Cage": {
    "firstname": "Johnny",
    "lastname": "Cage",
    "height": 183,
    "weight": 82,
    "hands": 2,
    "legs": 2
  }
}
```

---

```
jq -r 'to_entries[] | (.key | sub(" "; ".")) as $name 
       | .value | to_entries[]
       | "mk.fighter.\($name).\(.key) \(.value)"' input.json
```

To get `$name` as a combination of inner `firstname` and `lastname` keys replace 
`(.key | sub(" "; ".")) as $name` with `"\(.value.firstname).\(.value.lastname)" as $name`

---

The output:

```
mk.fighter.Johnny.Cage.firstname Johnny
mk.fighter.Johnny.Cage.lastname Cage
mk.fighter.Johnny.Cage.height 183
mk.fighter.Johnny.Cage.weight 82
mk.fighter.Johnny.Cage.hands 2
mk.fighter.Johnny.Cage.legs 2
```

Comment: How do I use .value.firstname and .value.lastname as $name? Not .key itself.  
EDIT: nevermind :) I managed.  
Spasibo Roman :)

Comment: @phear, welcome. I've added an update about `$name` varible